# SQL Server slow results with parameters

Tags: sql-server, performance, parameters

I have a query which selects some data, I pass some parameters in it:

```
DECLARE @FromAccDocNo     INT = 1,
        @ToAccDocNo       INT = 999999999,
        @FromDate         CHAR(10) = '1900/01/01',
        @ToDate           CHAR(10) = '2999/12/30',
        @L1Code           INT = 129

SELECT ad.AccDocNo,
       ad.AccDocDate,
       add1.Row,
       add1.RowComment,
       add1.Debit,
       add1.Credit
FROM   AccDoc ad
       INNER JOIN AccDocDetail add1
            ON  add1.AccDocNo = ad.AccDocNo
       INNER JOIN Topic t
            ON  t.TopicCode = add1.TopicCode
WHERE  t.L1Code = @L1Code -- here is the difference
       AND add1.AccDocNo BETWEEN @FromAccDocNo AND @ToAccDocNo
       AND ad.EffectiveDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
ORDER BY
       ad.AccDocNo
```

In first, I write the value 129 explicitly as `@L1Code` (it takes 0.010 sec)

In second form I pass `@L1Code` into query (it takes 2.500 sec)

Can anyone explain what happens?

Comment: They are variables not parameters. The two behave differently. Parameter values can be "sniffed". Variable values never are except if using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the canonical reference: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) (specifically this [bit](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#varparamreplace))

One way to fix, is to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of the query.